# How to store multiple relationships in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

If I have multiple objects and anyone can potentially map to multiple other ones.

```
A -> B, C, D, E
B -> A, E, F, C
C -> B
```

etc.

How would I store these entities in MySql and use JPA + Hibernate to manage them. For example, If I search "A", it will return "B,C,D,E", and if I search "C", it will return "B", etc.

Edited:

Follow suggestion, I did the following:

```
[test]> describe relation;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_start | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id_end   | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> describe entity;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from entity;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
|  3 | C    |
|  4 | D    |
|  5 | E    |
|  6 | F    |
+----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from relation;
+----+----------+--------+
| id | id_start | id_end |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        3 |      1 |
|  2 |        2 |      1 |
|  3 |        4 |      1 |
|  4 |        5 |      1 |
|  5 |        1 |      2 |
|  6 |        5 |      2 |
|  7 |        6 |      2 |
|  8 |        3 |      2 |
|  9 |        2 |      3 |
+----+----------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)



   [test]> select E.name, R.id_start from relation R join entity E on E.id=R.id_end where E.name="A";
+------+----------+
| name | id_start |
+------+----------+
| A    |        3 |
| A    |        2 |
| A    |        4 |
| A    |        5 |
+------+----------+
```

Question:

This query returns the related Ids of 'A', which is right, but not actually B, C, D, E. How to get the actual related names from entity table? Is it a database design or SQL statement mistake?

Comment: it's just a many-many relationship. so a table of entities (id, entity) and a link table (id_a, id_b)

Comment: @MarcB, please see the edited post. Thank you.

Comment: sql statement mistake. you need to select `R.name`. you're saying "give me all mars bars where chocolatebar = mars`, and then complaining you only got mars bars.

Comment: in other words, for a quick fix, do `select * from ...` instead, and you'll see get your expected results.

Comment: R (relation) has no 'name' field. It only has Ids.